# Set alphanumeric regex pattern not accepting certain specific symbols

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re

#Examples:
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 despues de 3 dias 2021-10-12" #NOT PASS
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 hsah555sahsdhj. Ya despues de 3 dias hjsdfhjdsfhjdsf 2021-10-12" #NOT PASS
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 hsah555sahsdhj; despues de 3 dias hjsdfhjdsfhjdsf 2021-10-12" #NOT PASS
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 hsah555sahsdhj despues de 3 dias hjsdfhjdsfhjdsf.\n 2021-10-12" #NOT PASS
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 hsah555sahsdhj; mmm... creo que ya despues de 3 dias hjsdfhjdsfhjdsf.\n 2021-10-12" #PASS
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 hsah555sahsdhj.    \n\n\n mmm... creo que ya despues de 3 dias hjsdfhjdsfhjdsf.\n 2021-10-12" #PASS


some_text = r"[\s|]*"  # <--- I NEED MODIFY THIS PATTERN
date_format = r"\d*-\d{2}-\d{2}"

check_00 = re.search(date_format + some_text + r"(?:(?:pasados|pasado|despues del|despues de el|despues de|despues|tras) (\d+) (?:días|día|dias|dia)|(\d+) (?:días|día|dias|dia) (?:pasados|pasado|despues del|despues de el|despues de|despues|tras))", input_text, re.IGNORECASE)
check_01 = re.search(r"(?:(?:pasados|pasado|despues del|despues de el|despues de|despues|tras) (\d+) (?:días|día|dias|dia)|(\d+) (?:días|día|dias|dia) (?:pasados|pasado|despues del|despues de el|despues de|despues|tras))" + some_text + date_format, input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

if not check_00 and not check_01: print("1")
else: print("0")
```

I need to set in the variable `some_text` a pattern that identify any alphanumeric substrings (that could possibly contain symbols included, such as `:` , `$`, `#`, `&`, `?`, `¿`, `!`, `¡`, `|`, `°`, `,` , `.`, `(`, `)`, `]`, `[`, `}`, `{` ), and with the possibility of containing uppercase and lowercase characters, **but the only symbols that should not to be present, not even once, are** `;` **and** `.\n` **or** `.[\s|]*\n*`

In this case I need to determine which cases does NOT meet, therefore, the `if not` conditionals in the code.

The **output** you should get if everything in the algorithm works fine would be this:

```
0  #for example 1
0  #for example 2
0  #for example 3
0  #for example 4
1  #for example 5
1  #for example 6
```

Is it possible, within the same pattern that I want to place in the `some_text` variable, to indicate a list with the symbols that I do NOT want to appear in that identification area of the pattern (in this case `;` and `.[\s|]*\n*` )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the only symbols that should not to be present, not even once, are ; and .\n or .[\s|]*\n*

For not allowing `;` you can simply use `[^;]`.

Regarding the other two "patterns": the `[\s|]` pattern makes a wrong assumption: a pipe symbol inside a character class will be interpreted *literally*. It seems you want to indicate with it that the `\s` is optional, but the asterisk already ensures this. The point must be escaped. So `\.\s*?\n`. But to *dis*allow it, you can put it in a negative look-ahead: `(?!\.\s*?\n)`.

This leads to:

```
some_text = r"(?:(?!\.\s*?\n)[^;])*"
```

Comment: Really thanks for the help, what is the difference between this pattern `(?:(?!\.\s*\n)[^;])*` and this pattern `(?:(?!\.\s*?\n)[^;])*` with this `?` ?

Comment: I added the `?` to make the `*` lazy, i.e. so that it stops grabbing `\s` as soon as it finds a `\n` (which would also match `\s`). Without it, it would keep grabbing all white space, including `\n`, and then would need to back track to find a `\n` that it should not grab. So `?` is preferred, but the outcome is the same.